# What happened to all the people with Senju last names?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, the Uchiha clan was wiped out by Itachi, which makes sense why you don't see many Uchihas in the show. However, why do I hardly see anyone anyone in the show with the last name of Senju? The last time I recalled, they weren't wiped out by anything. What's up with that?

Note: I know that the Narutopedia page for the [Senju Clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Senju_Clan) gives a short explanation, but I would like further elaboration.

Comment: i think they have done mixed marriage with other clans so much , that no pure senju exist as of now.

Comment: Tsunade is senju